# Extract rows and substrings from one file conditional on information of another file

Tags: string, bash, sed, awk, fasta

I have a file `1.blast` with coordinate information like this

```
1       gnl|BL_ORD_ID|0 100.00  33      0       0       1        3
27620   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|0 95.65   46      2       0       1       46
35296   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|0 90.91   44      4       0       3       46
35973   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|0 100.00  45      0       0       1       45
41219   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|0 100.00  27      0       0       1       27
46914   gnl|BL_ORD_ID|0 100.00  45      0       0       1       45
```

and a file `1.fasta` with sequence information like this

```
>1
TCGACTAGCTACGACTCGGACTGACGAGCTACGACTACGG
>2
GCATCTGGGCTACGGGATCAGCTAGGCGATGCGAC
...
>100000
TTTGCGAGCGCGAAGCGACGACGAGCAGCAGCGACTCTAGCTACTG
```

I am searching now a script that takes from `1.blast` the first column and extracts those sequence IDs (=first column `$1`) plus sequence and then from the sequence itself all but those positions between `$7` and `$8` from the `1.fasta` file, meaning from the first two matches the output would be

```
>1
ACTAGCTACGACTCGGACTGACGAGCTACGACTACGG
>27620
GTAGATAGAGATAGAGAGAGAGAGGGGGGAGA
...
```

(please notice that the first three entries from `>1` are not in this sequence)

The IDs are consecutive, meaning I can extract the required information like this:

```
awk '{print 2*$1-1, 2*$1, $7, $8}' 1.blast
```

This gives me then a matrix that contains in the first column the right sequence identifier row, in the second column the right sequence row (= one after the ID row) and then the two coordinates that should be excluded. So basically a matrix that contains all required information which elements from `1.fasta` shall be extracted

Unfortunately I do not have too much experience with scripting, hence I am now a bit lost, how to I feed the values e.g. in the suitable `sed` command?
I can get specific rows like this:

```
sed -n 3,4p 1.fasta
```

and the string that I want to remove e.g. via

```
sed -n 5p 1.fasta | awk '{print substr($0,2,5)}'
```

But my problem is now, how can I pipe the information from the first `awk` call into the other commands so that they extract the right rows and remove from the sequence rows then the given coordinates. So, `substr` isn't the right command, I would need a command `remstr(string,start,stop)` that removes everything between these two positions from a given string, but I think that I could do in an own script. Especially the correct piping is a problem here for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As either **thunk** and **msw** have pointed out, more suitable tools are available for this kind of task but here you have a script that can teach you something about how to handle it with `awk`:

Content of **script.awk**:

```
## Process first file from arguments.
FNR == NR {
        ## Save ID and the range of characters to remove from sequence.
        blast[ $1 ] = $(NF-1) " " $NF
        next
}

## Process second file. For each FASTA id...
$1 ~ /^>/ {
        ## Get number.
        id = substr( $1, 2 )

        ## Read next line (the sequence).
        getline sequence

        ## if the ID is one found in the other file, get ranges and
        ## extract those characters from sequence.
        if ( id in blast ) {
                split( blast[id], ranges )
                sequence = substr( sequence, 1, ranges[1] - 1 ) substr( sequence, ranges[2] + 1 )
                ## Print both lines with the shortened sequence.
                printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, sequence
        }

}
```

Assuming your `1.blasta` of the question and a customized `1.fasta` to test it:

```
>1
TCGACTAGCTACGACTCGGACTGACGAGCTACGACTACGG
>2
GCATCTGGGCTACGGGATCAGCTAGGCGATGCGAC
>27620
TTTGCGAGCGCGAAGCGACGACGAGCAGCAGCGACTCTAGCTACTGTTTGCGA
```

Run the script like:

```
awk -f script.awk 1.blast 1.fasta
```

That yields:

```
>1
ACTAGCTACGACTCGGACTGACGAGCTACGACTACGG
>27620
TTTGCGA
```

Of course I'm assumming some things, the most important that fasta sequences are not longer than one line.

Comment: That last assumption of yours IS dangerous, as [fasta-file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) (the use of which is often far from standardised) usually has a regular newline after a certain amount of characters. One of the reasons to go for Bioperl or something similar, as the respective methods will acount for (most of) the variations in file format.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still try to get through the code and understand what is happening there and adjust it (e.g. the output of the script shouldn't contain sequence `2` as it is not mentioned in the `blast` file). But I hope I'll manage from this point to work myself through it.

Comment: @thunk, good point with the dangerous assumptions, but one thing I haven't mentioned here - all those exercises are just to run certain blast searches and I do not use any other tools and I just call it here fasta, but I do not feed the files in any other program, I just need the sequences for a second blast search for the parts, that haven't been found in the previous run.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok. Didn't know that. Simply only print when the ID is found, inside de `if` instead after it.

Comment: @thunk: Yes. You are right. I had already seen some FASTA files before and knew it. Perhaps the OP has done some preprocessing of the input or something like that. I don't know. Otherwise it's a start and there is no issue in modifying the script to adapt it to his needs.

Comment: Thanks, the script helped indeed to understand more about `awk` and its use (especially as the example files given here were a bit simplified and hence I had to adjust the script still a bit).

Answer (score 2):

If you do bioinformatics and work with DNA sequences (or even more complicated things like sequence annotations), I would recommend having a look at [Bioperl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page). This obviously requires knowledge of Perl, but has quite a lot of functionality.

In your case you would want to generate [`Bio::Seq` objects](https://metacpan.org/module/Bio%3a%3aSeq) from your fasta-file using the [`Bio::SeqIO` module](https://metacpan.org/module/Bio%3a%3aSeqIO).

Then, you would need to read the fasta-entry-numbers and positions wanted into a hash. With the fasta-name as the key and the value being an array of two values for each subsequence you want to extract. If there can be more than one such subsequence per fasta-entry, you would have to create an array of arrays as the value entry for each key.

With this data structure, you could then go ahead and extract the sequences using the [`subseq` method from `Bio::Seq`](https://metacpan.org/module/Bio%3a%3aSeq#subseq).

I hope this is a way to go for you, although I'm sure that this is also feasible with pure bash.

Comment: +1: don't reinvent the wheel, especially if someone is giving wheels away for free

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I'll have a look at it. My background is R programming, so that makes things currently a bit difficult to switch the way of thinking... But I guess it's worth to get familiar with Bioperl as well.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, it is an attempt to clarify your problem; please let me know if I have gotten the nature of your task correct.

```
foreach row in blast:
    get the proper (blast[$1]) sequence from fasta
    drop bases (blast[$7..$8]) from sequence
    print blast[$1], shortened_sequence
```

If I've got your task correct, you are being hobbled by your programming language (bash) and the peculiar format of your data (a record split across rows). Perl or Python would be far more suitable to the task; indeed Perl was written in part because multiple file access in `awk` of the time was really difficult if not impossible.

You've come pretty far with the tools you know, but it looks like you are hitting the limits of their convenient expressibility.

Comment: Yes, your clarifications hit it pretty much on the head, this is what I am planning to do. In fact I took that as learning process for bash scripting, but I guess I'll follow your hint and switch to Perl (or Bioperl, thanks @thunk) and try my best there.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the answer:

```
awk  '
NR==FNR && NF { 
    id=substr($1,2)
    getline seq
    a[id]=seq
    next 
} 
($1 in a) && NF { 
    x=substr(a[$1],$7,$8)
    sub(x, "", a[$1])
    print ">"$1"\n"a[$1]
} ' 1.fasta 1.blast
```

Comment: @DanielFischer Updated the answer again. Would like to get your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was still busy to understand the answer from @Birei, hence I haven't answered yet and currently I do not have my data here, but on Monday I'll run the code on the data.

Comment: Thanks, this works as well as the solution from @Birei, so I would like to accept both, but this won't work unfortunately. But both answers help to understand `awk` better.